# Trouble with Javascript table colspan

Tags: javascript, html-table, winjs

I'm trying to make some of my columns span for readability, as well as pattern recognition. I'm also changing the background color of the cells to show patterns. If the data in my array is null, I use red. If it is not null and spans at least 2 columns, it is blue, otherwise, it is grey. I'm finding that some of my columns are wider than they should be, and some are shorter. With my data, the first columns are the only ones too wide, and the last are the only ones too short. So far as I can tell however, their colors are correct. I can give example code, but not example data as it is highly confidential. I can give the code, and will. Why are some of my columns wider, and others shorter than I expect them to be?

```
function loadTable() {
    var fields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("boxFields"));
    var report = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("boxReport"));
    var space = document.getElementById("batchReport");
    var baseList = document.createElement("ul");
    space.appendChild(baseList);
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        baseList.appendChild(li);
        var header = document.createElement("h2");
        header.textContent = fields[i] + ":";
        li.appendChild(header);
        if (report.length > 0) {
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.className += "wide";
            li.appendChild(table);
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            table.appendChild(tr);
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.colSpan = report.length;
            tr.appendChild(td);
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            table.appendChild(tr);
            var compare = "NeverEqual";
            var count = 0;
            td = null;
            for (var j = 0; j < report.length; j++) {
                if (compare == report[j][i]) {
                    count++;
                    td.colSpan = count;
                    if (compare != null)
                        td.style.backgroundColor = "#336";
                } else {
                    count = 1;
                    compare = report[j][i];
                    td = document.createElement("td");
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.textContent = report[j][i];
                    //td.colSpan = 1;
                    if (compare != null)
                        td.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
                    else {
                        td.style.backgroundColor = "#633";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    space.style.height = "93%";
    space.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? You've described what you're doing but not what the problem is. Also is there a reason you're using tables which are considered pretty deprecated vs the ms-grid layout?

Comment: Edited to have an explicit question. As for the ms-grid layout, a huge reason to use javascript is to be cross-platform. Tables should be fine in WinRT/JS, since it claims to be html5 compatible. I even think that for this purpose it is, I'm just counting wrong or something, but I'm overlooking it and asking for an extra set of eyes. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Your not specifying explicit widths for the table cells so they'll be auto calculated based on their content and the fallback logic the browser / IE does. If you want to have a cell have a specific width apply either a class to it or set it's with property explicity, e.g.:

```
td.style.width = "50px";
```

Or

```
td.className = "myCell";
// and in css somewhere define the class
.myCell{
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but I think its overlooking the idea that given enough space, each column should have the same weight, and when a cell spans mulitple columns it 'seems' like it should gain a proportionate weight. As you also might have seen, my tables are classed with 'wide', which I use to set with to 100%. Setting cell width won't correctly save this behavior. I'm not going to mark this as a correct answer, but I will give it a vote.